Are questions on specific implementations of crypto in a specific device/application/system on topic?
Would it be permissible to ask questions like "What sort of encryption does IE 9 support in HTTPS mode" or "What sort of cryptography does the iPhone use to keep user 3g data secure"?
Edit by Ninefingers:
We now have examples of questions to make this decision on. I think the best way might be to take them individually. Such questions include:

Cellular phone cloning - how does it work?
Authenticating data by a particular build of an open source program?

In both cases I think the location of these questions could be borderline. Migrating them or keeping them does affect our scope, so, I think in the interests of defining it it might be worth reviewing the above questions and deciding what we think. What do we think?
If anyone has any more examples we should consider, please edit - I had a brief look for other questions but couldn't see any at first glance.

I'd suggest those are not appropriate here, and should be migrated to IT Security - Stack Exchange.  I guess we'll be able to do that when we get some moderators assigned, within a few days.

I don't see a downside to allowing such questions here.
